# how to create a dataframe in R from " Min. 1stQu Median Mean 3rdQu Max. NA's"?

Tags: r, dataframe

[image]

how to create a dataframe in R from " Min. 1stQu Median Mean 3rdQu Max. NA's" ?? The Data of "Min. 1stQu Median Mean 3rdQu Max. NA's" is attached in the image.

```
Min.1stQu. Median Mean3rdQu. Max. NA's
0 25000 45000 66200 82000 615000 328
```

let the column name be "Income".
dataframe is attached!

And if I summarize the dataframe it should look like :

```
Summary(Income)

Min.1stQu. Median Mean3rdQu. Max. NA's
0 25000 45000 66200 82000 615000 328
```

Comment: `read.table(text = "Min. 1sQu. Median Mean 3rdQu. Max. NA's
      0 25000 45000 66200 82000 615000 328", header = T)`

Comment: hey thanks, but that would go to just columns names. 
I have edited the query if it helps!

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually asking (hence the down votes). Have a read through [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: yes, I believe andI I'll look to the link but I will ask you again this query! 

How you go about creating a dataframe of a single column from the data ( you can see in the picture)

Comment: `as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(summary(Income))))`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi names of what? min median max? no it doesnt

Comment: @rawr 'summary(Income)' doesn't exist, rather I have a data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the `tidy` function from the `broom` package. It is versatile and can organize most R statistical results into a data frame.

```
library(broom)
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(1000)
x[sample(1:length(x), 100)] <- NA
df <- tidy(summary(x))
df
  minimum      q1   median    mean     q3 maximum NA's
1  -3.008 -0.6834 -0.01371 0.00106 0.6978    3.81  100
```

As you can see, it is a data frame:

```
class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: How u go about reversing this?

Comment: @Hans you probably need another package for that, right Gopala?

Comment: Reversing what, I am sorry? As in convert back to some other class, not data frame?